# Create Tickets From TODO (or otherwise annotated) comments

Tags: source-code, trac, team-foundation-server

Is there any software that will allow me to generate trouble tickets (for Trac, Team Foundation Server, etc.) from TODO or otherwise annotated comments in the source code?

Comment: Note that Visual Studio can display TODO comments in a list of tasks. It's just a list, so of course, everything related to a real bug tracking system is missing.

Comment: IDEA does something similar.

Answer (score 1):

For Trac, there is a plugin called 'codetags' which provides a summary of encoded/tagged source comments without creating an actual ticket for each item.

http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/CodeTagsPlugin

Perhaps with some adaption or further extension, this plugin could help you create a ticket, or a batch of tickets based on tagged comments.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a package for [Atom Editor](https://atom.io) called [imdone-atom](https://atom.io/packages/imdone-atom) that can create, update and close GitHub issues from TODO comments in your code.  I'll be adding more integrations like Waffle.io, Jira and Phabricator and also a stand alone (non-atom) version soon.

Trac could be easily added if there is an open API.